# Forcing paracol to look like a tabular

Tags: tables, page-breaking, paracol

Consider the following `tabularx` construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{.4\linewidth}|X|}
  \hline
  \cellcolor{black!10}1 \lipsum*[1] & 2 \lipsum*[2] \\
  \hline
  \cellcolor{black!10}3 \lipsum*[2] & 4 \lipsum*[1] \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

All rules are included and one column is coloured. I'm interested in replicating the behaviour but using [`paracol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol). Here's a minimal example highlighting my shortcomings:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,paracol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\begin{document}

\raggedright

\columnratio{0.4}
\backgroundcolor{c[0]}{black!10}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  1 \lipsum[1]
  \switchcolumn
  2 \lipsum[2]
  \switchcolumn*
  3 \lipsum[2]
  \switchcolumn
  4 \lipsum[1]
  \switchcolumn*
  5 \lipsum[1]
  \switchcolumn
  6 \lipsum[2]
  \switchcolumn*
  7 \lipsum[2]
  \switchcolumn
  8 \lipsum[1]
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

In particular, the following still needs work:

1. Horizontal rules at top/bottom and inbetween *chunks*;
2. Vertical rules on the outside;
3. Equal separation between columns and vertical rules, similar to `\tabcolsep` (coloured separation in the coloured column, and not in the uncoloured one);

Is it possible to make the output of [`paracol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) match that of a `tabular`?

Motivation: A `tabular`-like structure that can break across the page boundary mid-row. I've tried using [`cals`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cals) which seem to [handle breaking at the page boundary](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/gE80AAOQ83U/woX-CFfUQYEJ), but the interface does not work as well for me.

Comment: Have you forgotten your own question?

Comment: @KeksDose: No. I'm actually working on it right now. Trying to find a pure [`paracol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) solution...

Comment: 1. There are three packages: paracol, parcolumns, parallel.\\ 2. Why paracol? I remember color stack bugs of the parallel package, but if you need, I can search for the solution I used years ago.

Comment: May I ask if you had success?

Comment: Did you surrender?

Comment: Still working on it?

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: You won't postpone your answer until 2015, will you?

Answer (score 2):

This seems not to be possible with paracol, because the paracol env can't be nested. But the parallel package does it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum,parallel, framed}

\newcommand\LR[2]{\begin{Parallel}[v]{0.35\textwidth}{0.55\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{#1}%
\ParallelRText{%
                                  \sffamily #2}%
                                 \ParallelPar
                                 \vspace{\baselineskip}%
                                 \end{Parallel}
                                 }

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\begin{document}

\raggedright


%\backgroundcolor{c[0]}{black!10}
\begin{framed}
\LR{\lipsum[1]}{\lipsum[2]} 
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\LR{\lipsum[1]}{\lipsum[2]} 
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\LR{\lipsum[1]}{\lipsum[2]} 

\end{framed}



\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image: parallel-with-lines]